# Generate multidimensional array based on given array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array say,

```
$arr = ["x", "y", "z"];
```

What I want to achieve is create another array based on given array such as

```
$arr1["x" =>["y" => ["z"]]] = "some value";
```

Any idea to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Edited:
    'some value' is just a dummy data. What I'm trying to achieve is the multidimensional structure.

Comment: Where does `some value` come from?  It's not clear from what you've said.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Kindly post some of your code/efforts, then only we can help you.

Comment: 1) Where does `some value` come from ? 2) You want to make multimentional array according to first array order ? Or you need to sort first array then do the multimentional array ?

Comment: @MickaëlLeger No, there is no need of sorting. I just need to make the multidimensional array according to first array order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$keys = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');
$value = 'some value';
$md = array();
$md[$keys[count($keys)-1]] = $value;
for($i=count($keys)-2; $i>-1; $i--)
{
  $md[$keys[$i]] = $md;
  unset($md[$keys[$i+1]]);
}
print_r($md);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I exactly needed.

Comment: @a.nivesh, unexplained and the most hard-to-understand answer, nice choose

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively build an array, taking and removing the first element of an array on each call :

```
function buildArray($arr, $someValue)
{
    if (count($arr) == 0)
        return $someValue;

    // the key is the first element of the array,
    // removed and returned at the same time using array_shift()
    return [ array_shift($arr) => buildArray($arr, $someValue) ];
}

$arr = ["x", "y", "z"];

$arr1 = buildArray($arr, "some value");

var_dump($arr1);

echo "------------------------" . PHP_EOL;
// note that $arr is preserved
var_dump($arr);
```

This outputs :

```
array(1) {
  ["x"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["y"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["z"]=>
      string(10) "some value"
    }
  }
}
------------------------
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "x"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "y"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "z"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is what I asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create recursive function:

```
 function rec_arr($ar, $val){ 
        $res = [];

        if(is_array($ar) && count($ar)>0){    
            $tmp = $ar[0];            // catching the first value
            unset($ar[0]);            // unset first value from given array
            sort($ar);                // makes indexes as 0,1,...
            $res[$tmp] = rec_arr($ar, $val);    // recursion
        } else {
            return $val;              // passing value to the last element
        }

        return $res;
 }
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/O2rZ9)**

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [x] => Array
        (
            [y] => Array
                (
                    [z] => some value
                )

        )

)
```